# Excel - repeating formulas when refreshing power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

So my problem is that I have a connection from sheet1 to sheet2 and in Sheet2, I calculate the total sum of the numbers in D2 but every time when I refresh the power query it automatically fills the same total sum (7129) to the end of the table. How can I prevent that happen? I have tried to disable the autofill formulas to table in `options->proofing->autocorrect options->autoformat as you type->fill formulas in tables to create calculated columns` but it doesn't help.

The example in the picture is a very simplified version of my actual calculations.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: I don't get your question: you want to calculate the sum, but you want to prevent the calculation from Happening? You can set calculation Options under the formula tab so that you have to manually click to recalculate the formulas, is that what you want?

Comment: I edited my post, I'm sorry that I didn't explain clear enough in the beginning.

Comment: i don't know anything about powerquery, so shot in the dark: can you rightclick column D and then get some Settings or Options or something? at least this will bump your question for more People to see

Comment: So, did you create Sheet1, then create a query from its table, and then (without doing anything else to that query) Close & Load that query to Sheet2 ... and then add in columns D & E? When I did that, I got the repeated entries, but I also got the button beside the cell to change AutoCorrect Options, and when I selected that button and "Undo Calculated Columns," I no longer had the repeated entries ... even after refreshing the query. I also tried what you mentioned didn't work for you ... disabling fill formulas via options ... and it worked fine for me.